# Garage door spring replacement

Tags: garage-door

Does anybody have any experience with changing Garador garage springs .   I would welcome any knowledge you have .  Cheers

Comment: Be aware that they can be/are very dangerous to the person working on them.  Can see these answers about a similar question.   https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/12762/how-do-i-replace-a-garage-door-spring?rq=1

Comment: I have done this several times.  It is a very dangerous DIY tasks without the proper tools and precautions during the process.  It involves multiple steps that require correctly tensioning the springs(s).  This would be one that worthwhile to check on the local shops and check their price.  I recently had one done at my son's house for about $150 including the springs.

Comment: I agree with programmer I do almost everything but these springs are seriously dangerous. New springs break and after knowing an installer that was almost killed , this is one of the very few jobs I leave to them.  I have done them and I have seen them break.

Comment: The one thing around the house I will not do : did once and got smart and not hurt. I recently has the torsion springs replaced , I called "the guy".  Don't even remember the cost , but well worth it.

Answer (score 2):

Some doors use a torsion spring wrapped around a bar above the door. Other doors use an extension spring which might be mounted parallel to the track on each side. Procedure is entirely different for one vs the other.

The main thing to understand is that an overhead garage door is a system with a LOT of stored energy. That in itself isn't unusual; we successfully deal with high-energy storage systems every day. Think of lithium-ion batteries in a laptop computer. Gasoline in a vehicle. Compressed air. A vehicle raised on a jack to allow repairs. To work with these things safely we think about the risks and take steps to mitigate them. Don't overheat batteries. Avoid spark and flame near gasoline vapors. Don't crawl under the raised vehicle until jack stands or cribbing are securely in place.

When working with a garage door system there are likewise precautions that can be taken to minimize risks. Lower the door to the ground if possible; if it must remain overhead then block it so it can't fall. Use pry bars of appropriate length for adding or removing tension in springs. Make sure the sockets or prying surfaces are in good condition so the pry bars will remain engaged well. Stand and keep body parts clear so that if the spring should break or a pry bar slips you (and others) are clear of the danger zone. Replace springs in pairs and tension equally to avoid overload.

It's not impossible to do but good situational awareness is vital. Some people have that knack and some don't. Honestly consider whether that's one of your strengths. If it isn't, bring in somebody who does have that knack.

The answer [there](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/12915/45928) in a question linked by crip659 is a good read.

Comment: No!   Raise the door and anchor it in place, with the door lowered the springs have more energy.

Comment: Also there's a thrird type of door where the spring is inside the roller that supports the door,

Comment: Thank you guys .   My overhead door has two springs each side .   There is a bracket at the bottom end which holds one loop of the spring and a pin in the middle of the door to the arm for the other end .   The only instruction there is, is lift and secure the door to release tension , then put spring on bottom bracket then lift spring onto pin .   Spring though is too strong to pull up . Too dangerous and hard for me , going for a pro

Comment: @Jasen The type of door with extension-type springs along the tracks probably should be done with the door raised (I'm not entirely sure about procedures; I've only had one of this style and never really worked on it so never had to figure it out). But the type with the torsion spring mounted on a bar above the door most definitely must be done with the door closed.